# count number of records based on percentages which are in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `Arraylist` which contains a list of records and in each single record I have percentage field.

I am trying to show the count of students who have percentage in between

> 40% to 50% ,
>   51% to 60% ,
>   61% to 70% ,
>   71% to 80% ,
>   81% to 90% ,
>   91% to 100% .

For Example, Suppose there are 5 students in between 61% to 70% I want to get the count as 5.
How can I get count of all students with specified percentages **dynamically**.
Can anyone please suggest me the approach to follow in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? As the list changes?

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically` ?

Comment: Does "dynamically"  mean "in any given range of percentage"?

Comment: Why don’t you sort them into a new set of `ArrayList`s, based on the percentage they are in between? Or simply have an array of counters (integers), each element in that array corresponding to a certain range between percentages?

Comment: Does the percentage represent a grade point average?

Comment: Well show a little bit of code to be understanded better . Each cell in the ArrayList is a Student item which has a field named `Percentage`? The ArrayList is sorted? 4 times readed and still not understand  .

Comment: dynamic means what I am tried to say is we can get while iterating the arrayList by using if(%>61 && %<70) with in if I can add count to other list and same for other percentages I am trying to know other alternate rather than this approach

Answer (score 6):

Don't count Students, count their percentages, like this:

```
int count = list.stream()
    .map(Student::getPercentage)
    .filter(n -> n >= low && n <= high)
    .count();
```

Being a Collection, an ArrayList lets us stream the Student objects, which are then converted to a stream of percentages, which then is filtered to keep only those percentages in the desired range, which are then counted.

---

To collect and iterate though ranges of 10 point brackets:

```
new TreeMap<>(list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getPercentage() / 10, Collectors.counting()))
.forEach((r, n) -> System.out.print(r + "0% to " + ++r + "0% had " + n));
```

This groups by the result of integer division by 10 (add a cast to the percentage to `int` if it's not an integer), adds a downstream counting operation, then processes each one.

The TreeMap wrapper puts the percentage ranges in order.

Comment: Could you try explaining it ?

Comment: I guess he wants to have something like Map<Pair<Int, Int>, Int> as result

Comment: @Shashwat so explained

Comment: in my jsp I am trying to display like percentages between 40% to 50% are 5 and percentages between 51% to 60% are 20 and up to percentages between 91% to 100% are 5 how can get the above result which is in an arrayList

Answer (score 2):

I would take the stream-approach a bit further:

```
Map<PercentageRange, Integer> counts =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( 
             student -> rangeOf(student.getPercentage())), 
             Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a lambda expression. This will get you a map with all specified ranges and the students.

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

//Each element will have the range as key and all students who fit in the range.
Map<MinMax, List<Student>> map = new HashMap();

//Add all ranges you want to filter your students-list by.
ArrayList<MinMax> minMaxes = new ArrayList<>();
minMaxes.add(new MinMax(20,40);
minMaxes.add(new MinMax(40,60);
minMaxes.add(new MinMax(60,80);

for (MinMax minMax : minMaxes) {
  map.put(minMax, students.stream().filter(u -> u.percentage < minMax.min && u.percentage > minMax.max).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

class MinMax {
  private int min;
  private int max;


  public MinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  public int getMin() {
    return min;
  }
  public void setMin(int min) {
    this.min = min;
  }
  public int getMax() {
    return max;
  }
  public void setMax(int max) {
    this.max = max;
  }

}
```